# htaccess redirect with white space, a quote and é

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, space, quote, diacritics

I have the following address:
`le%20coin%20de%20l’auteur%20-%20biographie%20de%20Cathérine%20Boullery.html`
which includes white spaces, a quote and a letter with an accent.

I would like to use something like:
`redirect 301 /this-above-url http://telecharger-ebook-roman-fantasy-aila-pdf-fr.fr//le-coin-de-l-auteur-biographie-de-catherine-boullery.html`

I have several pages with these strange characters to redirect and have no experience with `htaccess`, but I see, try to understand and copy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use quote around the url-path, and use the none-encoded characters. Something like the following

```
redirect 301 "le coin de l’auteur - biographie de Cathérine Boullery.html" http://telecharger-ebook-roman-fantasy-aila-pdf-fr.fr//le-coin-de-l-auteur-biographie-de-catherine-boullery.html
```

This did however not work on my test server.

What did work was using mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule "^le coin de l’auteur - biographie de Cathérine Boullery.html$" http://telecharger-ebook-roman-fantasy-aila-pdf-fr.fr//le-coin-de-l-auteur-biographie-de-catherine-boullery.html [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (and test). I also tested it (one never knows) and it also failed...

Comment: With other cases, I ensured that the rewrite rule was working. Here is an extract of my .htaccess file:
Options +FollowSymLinks

# redirect old pages
RewriteBase /
rewriteRule default.html http://telecharger-ebook-roman-fantasy-aila-pdf-fr.fr/index.html # OK
RewriteRule "^le coin de l’auteur - biographie de Catherine Boullery.html$" http://telecharger-ebook-roman-fantasy-aila-pdf-fr.fr/le-coin-de-l-auteur-biographie-de-catherine-boullery.html [R=302,L] # not OK

Comment: I notice there is no accent aigu in Catherine with your code. Secondly make sure the .htaccess file is saved with utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Thank you, the .htaccess file was ANSI. I made it UTF-8 (without BOM) and took your line again. You are correct, there was no accent aigu in Catherine (as I wanted to show the problem ' and é with one single line). I now have:    RewriteRule "^le coin de l’auteur - biographie de Catherine Boullery.html$" http://telecharger-ebook-roman-fantasy-aila-pdf-fr.fr//le-coin-de-l-auteur-biographie-de-catherine-boullery.html [R=302,L]    but it does not give a better result. I also tried with one slash in the new url (in case)...